# Segue arrays not passing why?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm at my wits end.  I've got basically the same thing working (but with a simpler function to generate the variables in a test project) but now my code is passing blank arrays to the next view controller.

I'm just wanting to pass 2 arrays, the values for which are generated through a function, to the next VC - I've triple checked my code and I'm sure I've done it right but obviously not! Any ideas!?

1st VC :

```
import UIKit

class WorkoutSetupController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var timeInputField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}

//Create function to generate a new random workout, with a random exercise array, and random reps array

func generateNewWorkout() -> (randomExerciseArray:[String], randomRepsArray:[Int]) {

    let randomKey = Int(arc4random_uniform(4) + 3)
    var workoutSet = [String]()
    let possibleExercises = masterExerciseArray
    var repsSet = [Int]()

    while workoutSet.count < (randomKey) {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(possibleExercises.count)))
        workoutSet.append(possibleExercises[randomIndex])
    }

    while repsSet.count < (randomKey) {
        repsSet.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(30)))
    }

    //return the values and print them to make sure the function is working (it is!)

    let workoutToBePassed = workoutSet
    let repsToBePassed = repsSet
    print (workoutToBePassed, repsToBePassed)
    return (workoutToBePassed, repsToBePassed)

}

//perform a manual segue to the WorkoutController page, using the function above to generate the values to be passed

@IBAction func workoutButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "doItNow", sender: generateNewWorkout())


}

//set the variables to be passed to the new VC, accepting the format of the returned arrays from my function for the variables

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "doItNow" {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? WorkoutController, let variablesToBePassed = sender as? (arr1:[String],arr2:[Int]) {

            print (variablesToBePassed.arr1, variablesToBePassed.arr2)

            destVC.selectedWorkoutExerciseArray = variablesToBePassed.arr1
            destVC.selectedWorkoutRepsArray = variablesToBePassed.arr2

        }
    }
}
}
```

second VC :

```
import UIKit

class WorkoutController: UIViewController {

//set the variables we're passing from the first VC with the right data type

var selectedWorkoutExerciseArray = [String]()
var selectedWorkoutRepsArray = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func printButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //print the variables out - this is currently printing blank arrays arghhghghghh!

    print (selectedWorkoutExerciseArray, selectedWorkoutRepsArray)

}
```

}

Where am I going wrong!?  I can't see it anywhere! Please help!

Comment: tried to print them iside prepareForSegue in if let destVC = ?? or inside generateNewWorkout before return ??

Comment: I've printed inside the function before the return - just to make sure the function is actually producing arrays correctly which it is

Comment: inside if let  ????

Comment: sorry what do you mean?  I haven't been printing it there but have added it and amended my code above, it doesn't do anything there though

Comment: You need to debug the problem in the first VC, not the second one. Check if the arrays are generated properly in your `generateNewWorkout()` and also that your other print in `prepare(for segue...` prints expected results.

Comment: Also using `sender` to pass custom data might be considered anti-pattern as the purpose of `sender` is different.

Comment: thanks - that helped - i've just realised i needed to make the variable names that i declare in my function the same as the ones i declare in my prepare for .... (changed them both to 'randomExerciseArray', 'randomRepsArray' instead of 'arr1', 'arr2', thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tom what's the 'proper way' to do this if not this way?  (still learning any help useful even if just pointing in right direction!)

Comment: Well, in your case I can't see a reason why can't you generate your data in the `prepare(for segue...)` directly.

Comment: that's a good point thanks - coming at it the other round, when wouldn't you do that?  i.e. why doesn't everyone do that all the time when they're preparing segues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter labels of the tuple don't match, you have to check

```
let variablesToBePassed = sender as? (randomExerciseArray:[String], randomRepsArray:[Int]) {
```

---

This is a good example of the benefit of force unwrapping objects which **must** have a value of the expected type

```
  let destVC = segue.destination as! WorkoutController
  let variablesToBePassed = sender as! (arr1:[String],arr2:[Int])
```

If the code crashes it reveals the **design** error at once.